# How is a piped rxjs operator possibly affected by a subsequent operator's returned value?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In order to inspect intermediate values between operators in an rxjs pipe, I am trying to use tap for simply logging them to the console.

I have two taps, one before a map operator that is used for sorting an Array, and one after it. What surprised me is, that **for both taps, the same sorted Array is logged, while I expected to see the original order first, and then the sorted one**.

So the sorting in the map operator affects the observable used by the previous tap operator. Nonetheless, the operators' functions seem to be executed one after another as expected, since the log of the second map is logged inbetween the taps' logs.

My code (I intend to replace the Observable Array's type with a proper one later on):

```
public getJSONData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.poisJSONPath).pipe(
      map((featureCollection: any) => featureCollection.features),
      tap((features) => console.log(features)),
      map((features: any) => {
        console.log('this is logged in between as expected');
        return features.sort((a, b) =>
          a.properties.name > b.properties.name ? 1 : -1
        );
      }),
      tap((features) => console.log(features))
    );
  }
```

I assume I am missing some fundamental feature of the rxjs pipes' mode of operation. In all other examples I found, the tap seems to work as I expect. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, (but not only) answer is that the array is already sorted.

---

Looking into it further, when I run this:

```js
of({
  features: [3,4,7,1,3,8]
}).pipe(
  pluck('features'),
  tap(console.log),
  map(features => {
    console.log('this is logged in between as expected');
    return features.sort(
      (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1
    );
  }),
  tap(console.log)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

This is my output:

```html
[3,4,7,1,3,8]
this is logged in between as expected
[1,3,3,4,7,8]
[1,3,3,4,7,8]
```

So, this might have something to do with the environment you're running in.

If, for example, `console.log` gets buffered - then perhaps the array has already changed in memory before it's printed even though the printing order is preserved.

---

#### A Consideration

RxJS doesn't make any guarantees about what is in memory. That's why you're encouraged to use pure, non-mutating functions. So that your program logic is easier to reason about.

Consider this:

```js
const delayedLog = val => setTimeout(() => console.log(val), 1000);

of({a: 5}).pipe(
  tap(delayedLog),
  map(input => {
    delayedLog("this is logged in between as expected");
    input.a++;
    return input;
  }),
).subscribe(delayedLog);
```

output:

```html
{"a":6}
this is logged in between as expected
{"a":6}
```

`{"a":6}` is printed twice even though a = 5 at the time the first delayed log is called. That's because the value changes in memory before the console reads the value from memory.

Vs

```js
const delayedLog = val => setTimeout(() => console.log(val), 1000);

of({a: 5}).pipe(
  tap(delayedLog),
  map(input => {
    delayedLog("this is logged in between as expected");
    return { a: input.a + 1 }
  }),
).subscribe(delayedLog);
```

```html
{"a":5}
this is logged in between as expected
{"a":6}
```

Here we get the expected output because we don't mutate our object, we return a new object with the incremented value.

---

#### A place to start looking

Try sorting a shallow copy of the array and see if that fixes it for you.

```js
public getJSONData(): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.poisJSONPath).pipe(
    pluck('features'),
    tap(console.log),
    map((features: any[]) => {
      console.log('this is logged in between as expected');
      return [...features].sort((a, b) =>
        a.properties.name > b.properties.name ? 1 : -1
      );
    }),
    tap(console.log)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your explanation complements my initial vague guesses. I first tried your example with numbers, which still gave me the same sorted result for both taps when I inserted it into my function and subscribed from another component. When I subscribed directly within the component like in your code, my output was the same as yours, so the environment plays a role here, indeed.
Your added considerations clarified the problem for me very well and using a shallow copy now works for me as well, no matter where i subscribe.